# Host has no libpng library

Tags: gem5

I am working with gem5. Recently I have updated Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I have installed all the necessary dependencies for gem5 as well as libraries "libpng-dev" I can find two versions of libpng in my system libpng as well as libpng16. Even then I get error  Header file <png.h> not found. I also changed the file path in configs folder to lib16/png.h still the error persists. Kindly help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Sadhana, the most precise thing you can try to do is to diff your system with whatever the Docker is doing: https://askubuntu.com/questions/350475/how-can-i-install-gem5/1275773#1275773 The other thing you should try is to understand which files you have installed with `locate` and `pkdg` +  a minimal C example what includes the PNG header + -l. Then you determine if it is a PATH problem, or missing file problem. I'm building find in 20.10 BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.My problem is resolved.

Comment: @SadhanaRai what was the solution?

Comment: I was using python3 so I had to install pydot using pip3 install pydot